# In Angular, keep environment.ts a separate file in bundling for browser?

Tags: angular

When doing an Angular production build for browser, the file environment.ts (after being replaced by environment.prod.ts) gets minimized, uglified and bundled.

Is there a way to prevent this, so that environment.ts remains a separate, non-uglified file in the browser bundle?

(I still want the rest of the code to be optimized for production of course.)

Rationale: I’d like to distribute the pre-built bundle to different server admins for installation on their servers, and they need to make local adjustments to environment.ts. I want to spare them the effort to do a local build only because they need to adjust one value in environment.ts.

Comment: The environments feature is for build-time configuration, sounds like you want deploy- or run-time which it doesn't help you with. I've written about some useful patterns here: https://blog.jonrshar.pe/2020/Sep/19/spa-config.html

Comment: That is very helpful! Ideal would be deploy-time, but your run-time solutions are good enough for me! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I had the same need for single build to be deployed to multiple environments in Bamboo ecosystem. To achieve my goal I was using tokens as values in environment.prod.ts and replace them in main.js bundle with plain grep

eg

```
envioronment.prod.ts
{
     backendUrl:CI_BACKEND_URL
     somethingElse: CI_SOMETHING_ELSE
}
```

and during the deployment process I was simply using `grep` to replace `CI_BACKEND_URL` with required values (which were deployment dependent) in the `main.js`  file.

This is what your "admins" could do.

Comment: This is what I currently do. Even replacing the whole inside of the environment object definition {...} by the contents of a separate file using sed at deploy-time. But it feels like an awefully dirty hack...